# What is the Visual Studio Standard Collector process, and why does it use 10GB of RAM?

Tags: windows, memory, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Hopefully this is the right stack exchange site to post on... Didn't feel like it was a programming question for SO. Anyway, I'm running Visual Studio 2015 and got a notification to from Windows to close VS2015 because it's running low on memory. I have 24GB of RAM and just rebooted yesterday, so I think something is way off here. I sometimes use the C# interactive window, and python 2.7 interactive window, but those were not in use at the time of this message.

Note: As I'm writing this, I just got an "Unknown hard crash" message from devenv.exe (vs2015 process). But the Standard Collector service is still running using up 10.7GB.

Does anyone know what the Standard Collector is? And what might cause the RAM usage to spike?

Note: Again as I'm writing, I just noticed the Standard Collector Service stopped in my task manager and I have all my RAM back.

[image: Large RAM usage by a Visual Studio "Standard Collector" process]

**Update:** It sounds like this might be a bug that the VS team tried to fix in update 1. I definitely have update 1 installed, but perhaps I should try to reproduce in some sample code and send it to the VS team. The devenv instance that crashed was also not currently debugging. (Although, there is another instance where it is debugging as you can see by the .vshost.exe extension in task manager)

That devenv instance did not crash and it's actually still running in the debugger now without problems.

[image]

Comment: [It deals with Diagnostic Tools.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cd1d1c57-fbf0-4076-a708-5e9516f359b1/visual-studio-standard-collector-service-disabled-for-productivity-during-debugging?forum=visualstudiogeneral).  You are aware that Chrome exists as a 64-bit process right?

Comment: this is a known bug and it has a fix with an update check here for info :
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1630071/visual-studio-standard-collector-unbounded-memory-usage

Comment: @arana, I'm running update 1, which "should" have the fix...

Comment: @Ramhound Chrome isn't really relevant to this question. Or are you just kindly sharing a useful tidbit of information?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The Collector Process appears to be related to instrumentation/diagnostics of code running in debug mode, in Visual Studio 2015. Microsoft has acknowledged there is an issue with unbounded memory use of this process, and says,

> We have researched the root cause and have made a fix that will be
>   provided in VS2015 Update 1

So make sure you get the latest Visual Studio 2015 update.
For mitigation in the meantime:

> Meanwhile, if you notice that the process consumes too much memory
>   you have two ways to recover. Simplest is just to restart your
>   machine. That will get everything back to a fresh state. The other
>   thing you can do to alleviate the memory consumption is to stop the
>   Visual Studio Standard Collector Service using the Service Manager UI.
>   The Name of the service is "VSStandardCollectorService140". It can be
>   safely stopped when you not debugging with Visual Studio. If you stop
>   the service while debugging (even stopped at a breakpoint) then the
>   Diagnostic Tools window will display an error message after you resume
>   the debug target process.

Look at [this link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1630071/visual-studio-standard-collector-unbounded-memory-usage), where the above quotes are sourced from.

This link also has a code example of someone who experienced this from a console app.  It could be worth running that sample code to see if it triggers the issue on your system.  The person who reported the issue also indicated it occurred intermittently, but running the code in Visual Studio debugging mode seemed to be the one common thread.

Possibly Microsoft fixed some root causes of the issue, but there are still other unfixed causes now surfacing.

Comment: One simple way (Windows 7/Windows 10) to bring up the Services GUI is to do Start/Run and type "services.msc" and press Enter.  In the list of services on my Windows 7 machine, the name I believe to be the one mentioned shows as "Visual Studio Standard Collector Service".

Comment: Interesting, although I do have Update 1 installed -> hence why I use c# interactive window (only available in Update 1). Interesting that the example code from your link that the guy reproduced uses Tasks. My application makes fair use of tasks and async code as well.

Comment: @matrixugly, as I understand the issue, the Collector Service is basically running all the time when VS2015 is running, collecting app instrumentation/diagnostic info. So what you were doing at the time when Windows gave the low memory alert may or may not have any relation to the issue.  It could have been something much earlier, where the Collector Service process failed to recognize it needed to start clearing out old instrumentation data, gradually filled up memory, and the message appeared hours later during an unrelated activity.

Comment: I think that makes sense. Your answer mentions that it has to do with VS2015 diagnostic tools and that it was even an issue known to Microsoft before update 1. I agree that it seems like the service didn't recognize when it should have started shutting down/cleaning stuff up. That's satisfactory enough for me to accept your answer. I appreciate you finding the workaround too.

Comment: @matrixugly - My comment made mention of that.............

Comment: @Ramhound. OK. Wasn't sure who posted first. I was also confused by the Chrome mention.

Comment: @Ramhound, the Chrome mention confused me too, so I kept looking and didn't see there was a link in your comment.  In any case, until MS issues a working, permanent fix, the most effective mitigation, with multiple sources suggesting it, seems to be going into Services and stopping the Visual Studio Standard Collector Service.

Comment: Still exists in Update 3 RC. :(

Comment: There is Update 3 hotfix. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt752379.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Issue 6
This fix addresses a memory leak in the StandardCollector.Service.exe process. You commonly encounter this leak when you debug managed code on Windows 7 that has Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 installed.

Comment: Is this still a problem for VS2017? If so what are the consequences of disabling this service?

Answer (score 23):

> Disable the service and it won't eat your memory again.

Tools->Options->Debugging->General, disable "Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging".

Comment: You should also mention that you won't have diagnostic tools which are part of the debugging suite that a lot of people use.

Comment: Personally, as a developer, I always disabled diagnostic tools because I felt it made my machine a lot slower since the first time I've seen it, and only enable it when I actually have a performance problem I need to diagnose (which is quite rare), and still, a profiling session usually give me much more information. I'm quite curious to know what would people use it for on a regular basis.