# Temp files sc.kernel.X.etl are generated weekly and take over several dozen of gigaoctets

Tags: google-chrome, adobe-photoshop, visual-studio, temporary-files, unity3d

[EDIT : Opened the files in the event logger]

[image: Event logger]

It seems that the error are logged really often : Error 15003 seems to be a driver error, though no yellow ! shows up in the peripheral manager.

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="" Guid="{ce1dbfb4-137e-4da6-87b0-3f59aa102cbc}" /> 
  <EventID>0</EventID> 
  <Version>2</Version> 
  <Level>0</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>46</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-05-13T20:31:48.544092000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>96360642</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4294967295" ThreadID="4294967295" ProcessorID="0" KernelTime="0" UserTime="0" /> 
  <Channel /> 
  <Computer>XXXXXXXX</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <ProcessingErrorData>
  <ErrorCode>15003</ErrorCode> 
  <DataItemName /> 
  <EventPayload>4EAA0F0C00000000FC31000001005000</EventPayload> 
  </ProcessingErrorData>
  </Event>
```

[Initial post]

My main hard drive gets saturated weekly and I have to delete those files manually. 
Does somebody know where it comes from ?

Software I use on a daily basis : Photoshop, Unity3D, Chrome, Visual studio, 
Visual code and ConEmu

Temps files are all named sc.kernel.[Number].etl didn't find anything on the subject.

I scanned the computer with windows defender as well, no results.

[image]

Comment: What Windows version are you using?

Comment: .etl files are Windows event log files. If you open one of them with event log viewer, what kind of messages does it contain?

Comment: I'm using windows 10 x64 Pro. Also they don't get cleaned up with disk tools utility. I'm trying @TilmanSchmidt suggestion.

Comment: I opened the file in the event log viewer, and edited my post.

Comment: GUID {ce1dbfb4-137e-4da6-87b0-3f59aa102cbc} is PerfInfo according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx so it seems this is related to performance counters. IMHO that makes Visual Studio the most probable culprit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same. I couldn't make out a lot of helpful info in eventviewer - which also took several hours to open my 40GB file.

In the details, I found a ProcessId of a process that was still running, StandardCollector.Service.exe, related to Visual Studio diagnostics.
I assume I had a very long debugging session running over night.

The debugging diagnostics can also be disabled if not used, see https://superuser.com/a/1315655/146668 .

Comment: I'll validate this as the answer. Can't remember the exact things I did to solve the issue but I can recall it was linked to VS .